# a:active not working on mobile device

Tags: javascript, iphone

my question is: Why this div(with class="menu_cent") not working the class .menu_cent:active, when I clicking on it on mobile devices, but on desktop its works.

```
    <div class="m_10">
        <a href="#" onclick="set_lng('en')"><div class="menu_cent">English</div></a>
    </div>

    .menu_cent   
{background:#fff;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;word-wrap:break-word;min-height:16px;background:#FFF;border:1px solid #d9d9d9;padding:10px;line-height:1.3;text-align:center;font-size:16px;color:#888;font-weight:700;cursor:pointer}

    .menu_cent:active   
{background:#f1f1f1;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;word-wrap:break-word;min-height:16px;background:#FFF;border:1px solid #d9d9d9;padding:10px;line-height:1.3;text-align:center;font-size:16px;color:#888;font-weight:700;cursor:pointer}
```

I had tried to use

```
<div class="m_10">
    <a href="#" onclick="set_lng('en')"><div onClick="style.backgroundColor='#f1f1f1';" class="menu_cent">English</div></a>
</div>
```

it works but it comes with delay.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

If you want the link to be the target, you're putting the active pseudo class on the wrong element.  Here's how you'd want to approach it:

```
a:active div.menu_cent{
 property: blah;
}
```

Otherwise, you can set the div:active (I know this works in WebKit browsers, don't know about others), but generally you'll want the :active and :visited pseudo classes on anchor elements primarily.

**ALSO** you have your background set twice in that :active block.  Which is partly why you're not seeing any change.